# Auth from lambda to call AppSync with apikey

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I'm trying to create a timeout function that is calling AppSync

```js
const timeout = parseInt(process.env.TIMEOUT);
const graphqlEndpoint =
  'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql';
require('isomorphic-fetch'); // Required for 'aws-appsync'

// Initialize GraphQL client
//const AWS = require('aws-sdk/global');
const AUTH_TYPE = require('aws-appsync').AUTH_TYPE;
const AWSAppSyncClient = require('aws-appsync').default;
const gql = require('graphql-tag');
const config = {
  url: graphqlEndpoint,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  auth: {
    type: AUTH_TYPE.API_KEY,
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  },
  disableOffline: true,
};
const gqlClient = new AWSAppSyncClient(config);
// The mutation query
const mutation = gql`
  mutation disconnect($id: ID!) {
    disconnect(id: $id)
  }
`;

exports.handler = async function () {
  const timestamp = Date.now() - timeout; // timeout could be 15 seconds
  // Retrieve the list of ids and remove them
  try {
    const ids = [1, 2, 3]; // TODO: get all ids with timestamp bigger than lastConnectedOn
    if (!ids.length) return { expired: 0 };
    // Create and send all mutations to AppSync
    const promises = ids.map(id =>
      gqlClient.mutate({ mutation, variables: { id } })
    );
    await Promise.all(promises);
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

The article is here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/gametech/building-a-presence-api-using-aws-appsync-aws-lambda-amazon-elasticache-and-amazon-eventbridge/

I changed the auth part because I want to use apiKey for development purposes.
But when I run the lambda I get

```
{
  "graphQLErrors": [],
  "networkError": {
    "name": "ServerError",
    "response": {
      "size": 0,
      "timeout": 0
    },
    "statusCode": 401,
    "result": {
      "errors": [
        {
          "errorType": "UnauthorizedException",
          "message": "Valid authorization header not provided."
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "message": "Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 401"
}
```

I know AppSync needs x-api-key header, but I'm not sure how to add it.

Or am I just plain wrong for trying to use apiKey from the lambda and have to search for another AUTH_TYPE?

Thanks guys

Edit: In this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-node.html#aws-appsync-building-a-client-app-node there is the option to create an apiKey, but there is no example in how to use it.